# Java try and finally blocks in a multithreading example

Tags: java, multithreading, try-finally

I'm new here and to Java.  I was reading about Java concurrency in the Oracle Java Tutorial, specifically the section about Lock Objects [Link to Page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/newlocks.html).  The thing that I can't seem to understand is why the try and finally blocks are used in the impendingBow() and bow() methods;

```
public boolean impendingBow(Friend bower) {
    Boolean myLock = false;
    Boolean yourLock = false;
    try {
        myLock = lock.tryLock();
        yourLock = bower.lock.tryLock();
    } finally {
        if (! (myLock && yourLock)) {
            if (myLock) {
                lock.unlock();
            }
            if (yourLock) {
                bower.lock.unlock();
            }
        }
    }
    return myLock && yourLock;
}
public void bow(Friend bower) {
    if (impendingBow(bower)) {
        try {
            System.out.format("%s: %s has"
                + " bowed to me!%n", 
                this.name, bower.getName());
            bower.bowBack(this);
        } finally {
            lock.unlock();
            bower.lock.unlock();
        }
    } else {
        System.out.format("%s: %s started"
            + " to bow to me, but saw that"
            + " I was already bowing to"
            + " him.%n",
            this.name, bower.getName());
    }
}
```

Would those two sections of code work without the try-finally blocks? Will the tryLock() function throw an exception I'm not aware of?

Comment: I imagine that yes, there's an implication that `tryLock()` could throw an exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is kind of a contrived example. I think that the `try-finally` blocks are used here as an attempt to reinforce the practice of releasing locks in a `finally` block.

But it could be useful in some rare cases; it is possible an error could be thrown. Another thread can cause any exception to be raised in the current thread by using `Thread.stop()`, or a runtime error like `OutOfMemoryError` could occur.

In one of these error cases, however, `impendingBow()` could exit holding both locks, and these wouldn't be released by the caller, `bow()`. So, this code is not exemplary. It shows perfunctory compliance with the practice of releasing locks in a `finally` without really thinking things through.

Comment: It's even easier than that. System.out.format will throw IllegalArgumentExceptions when types don't match placeholders. You don't want a typo in debugging code to cause you to leak locks.

Comment: I was not aware of the practice of releasing locks.  This is starting to make more sense.  Thank you.

Comment: @DavidEhrmann Here, I am emphasizing that even if the code in the `try` blocks is bug-free (as it is), there are runtime conditions outside the programmer's control that can raise exceptions. Type problems in a format statement are a bug that should be caught by unit testing.